# tcl/tk: want to plot chart and histogram with tcl, what special package needed?

Tags: charts, plot, package, tcl, tk-toolkit

I want to plot chart with tcl/tk. what special package do I need? If possible, the I don't want to use special packages. Do default tcl package has plot functions? 
Thanks

Comment: For a basic one, you can use the Tk package and use the [canvas widget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm). You will have to draw everything on the chart AFAIK, i.e. the axes, and lines/polygons etc.

Comment: @Jerry,thank you
but draw everything by myself sounds crazy. I am not familiar with tcl/tk at all. so does the default tcl package has plot functions?

Comment: Not that I know of, but from a bit of googling, [this](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11265) came up which I think might help you. Some pictures of this external package can be found at the end of [this page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/18167).

Comment: thank you.I see your point. Maybe I can create my own package by TK canvas widget.

Answer (score 0):

Though Tk comes with the basic tools (the `canvas` widget), it's not specialised to plotting. You're going to have to use a package or write your own (which can be a little bit fiddly).
The [Plotchart](http://core.tcl.tk/tklib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tklib/files/modules/plotchart/plotchart.html) package in Tklib is pure Tcl and recommended unless you're doing something *really* complicated.